# How to grant limited access to accounts?

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, permission-sets, roles

I have a support rep that his role has access to ALL accounts.

Support role does NOT have access to opptys.

There is a request now to give a specific support rep, access to a specific account opptys data (view only)

How can I achieve that?

If I give him any permission to view Opptys - he will see ALL opptys (since he can see all accounts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the manual share for the specific opportunity as explained at http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_access_to_records.htm rather than giving him access to opportunities as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you can set the sharing setting for Opportunity to Private and then share the needed opportunities to that support rep.

Comment: I think this is from OWD - and I will not change that. It's not set to private now, so I will not change it.

Comment: Manual sharing of opportunities will come into picture only if the OWD for opportunities is set to private.